# Uniform bound of an integral of a sum of cosines

Tags: real-analysis, integration, singular-integrals

Let's define an integral

$$\int_{\epsilon}^{\eta} \cos(2\pi Rr |x'\cdot y'|) - \cos(2 \pi R r) \frac{dr}{r} $$

where $0<\epsilon<\eta < \infty$, $R>0$ and $x',y'\in \mathbb{R^n}$ (not really important since $|x'\cdot y'|$ is just a positive real number). This integral comes up in a proof on singular integrals commuting with dilations in Steins book *"Singular Integrals and Differentiability Properties of Functions"* by Stein on page 40f if anyone is interested.

The claim is that this integral is uniformly bounded in $\epsilon$ and $\eta$ by

$$ C + C\log\frac{1}{|x'\cdot  y'|} $$

(where $\log$ is the natural logarithm) *"as an integration by part shows"* (Stein is known for his notorious understatement of not-so-trivial observations). Can anyone help me out how to see this?